# Suming fetched values from foreach loop

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl, el

I have a JSP page and I managed to multiply each cena with kolicina.

```
<c:forEach items="${proizvodKorpa}" var="proizvod">
    <tr>
        <td>${proizvod.proizvod}</td>
        <td>${proizvod.cena}</td>
        <td>${proizvod.kolicina}</td>
        <td>${proizvod.cena * proizvod.kolicina}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Ukupno</td>
    <td>SUM GOES HERE</td>
</tr>
```

Now the problem is how  to sum total of each dynamically generated value and display it outside the foreach loop? Here's what I want to get :

[image: Result wanted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<c:set var="sum" value="${0}" /><!-- use "${0}" for numeric value, "0" could be interpreted as string -->
<c:forEach items="${proizvodKorpa}" var="proizvod">
    <tr>
        <td>${proizvod.proizvod}</td>
        <td>${proizvod.cena}</td>
        <td>${proizvod.kolicina}</td>
        <td>${proizvod.cena * proizvod.kolicina}</td>
    </tr>
    <c:set var="sum" value="${sum + (proizvod.cena * proizvod.kolicina)}" />
</c:forEach>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Ukupno</td>
    <td><c:out value="${sum}" /></td>
</tr>
```